# wxGrid shows the old value instead of new value after user edits a cell

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxwidgets

I created the wxGrid in editablemode. I registered the following event handler.

```
class ReadWriteGrid : public wxGrid
{
public:
ReadWriteGrid(wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID ID,
            const wxPoint &pos=wxDefaultPosition, const wxSize &size=wxDefaultSize,
            long style=262144, const wxString &name=wxGridNameStr)
            : wxGrid(parent, ID, pos, size, style, name)
{
    SetEditable();
}
```

};

> EVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGE(IndexTableFrame::OnEditField)

Now when user changes the cell value my function gets called but after it completes. The cell value changes back to its old value.

```
void IndexTableFrame::OnEditField(wxGridEvent& event)
 {
int RowNumber;
int ColNumber;
wxString type;
wxGridCellEditor *m_Editor;
wxString NewValue;
RowNumber = event.GetRow();
ColNumber = event.GetCol();
m_Editor = m_grid->GetDefaultEditorForCell(RowNumber,ColNumber);
NewValue = m_Editor->GetValue();
m_Editor->Destroy();
m_grid->SetCellValue(NewValue,RowNumber,ColNumber);
event.skip();   
   }
```

This is the first time I am using WxWidget. I am not sure how to avoid the cell from changing back to its old value.

Answer (score 0):

You are working too hard!  Relax and let wxGrid take the strain.

The simplest thing to do is to do nothing.  wxGrid will accept user edits in cells and display the changes without you having to do anything.  When the user is finished, he can click a button SAVE, where you can implement code to read the values from the cells and use them for whatever you need.

Comment: ,ya I tried doing nothing.The table that is attached to this grid is quite complex. After the user edits the cell value in grid, the changes are not passed to table underneath. After loosing focus the grid calls getcellvalue(row,col) of the table which returns back the original value that it reads from a file.

Comment: Then I believe the problem is in the way you 'attached' the table 'underneath'.  If you do that properly, then the wxWidgets framework should look after things for you.  However, that is pretty advanced stuff and I am not an expert in doing that.

Answer (score 0):

In many applications, one has to do processing on the cell value on the fly as the user changes it, (for example to update other on-screen controls on the fly based on the new cell values; or to send data via a serial port to another device immediately as the cells are changed).

Requiring the user to click a separate "save button" as suggested above is not a solution that will be acceptable to users in many use cases.

I can confirm the observations by the original poster: If you create a wxGrid and attach either wxEVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGED, wxEVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGING, or wxEVT_GRID_EDITOR_HIDDEN events to it, a call to grid->GetCellValue(row,col); returns the old value. The event parameter to the handler function also does not contain the new text. It looks like a "feature" of wxGrid.

Comment: I can't confirm this.  When `wxEVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGED` is emitted the grid contains the new value.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own class inherited from [wxGridTableBase](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_grid_table_base.html).

Then you should attach your grid table object to the wxGrid, using it's [SetTable](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_grid.html#af7ddc545bc6f1c84f63982e3d9bcb5d5) method.

wxGrid object will use your table's methods (GetValue, SetValue) to retrieve and store data.

There's a grid sample shipped with wxWidgets, that will help you understand how does wxGrid work.